# Shortcut keys clashing with IntellIj Shortcut keys. How to resolve this?

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, intellij

Ubuntu Shortcut keys are clashing with IntelliJ IDEA shortcut keys.

Example
Ctrl+Alt+L
This formats the code in IntelliJ IDEA
While this locks the ubuntu desktop. Also Windows+L also locks the desktop.

I want to only use Windows+L key to lock desktop, so that Ctrl+Alt+L can be used in IntelliJ IDEA.

Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

## IntelliJ case

Go to: `File | Settings | Keymap` and change to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for instance:

[image]

## Or Ubuntu case:

Go to `System Settings | Keyboard` and change `Lock screen` option:

[image]

Comment: How about shortcuts that are not listed under `System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts`? (like `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F7`)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you use `Ctrl + Alt` in OS as layout change keys combination, for example.

Try using `Left Ctrl + Left Alt` to separate OS and Intellij key listeners. In this case more general Intellij's `Ctrl + Alt + Slash` keys combination will work for the right side keys combination in IDE: `Right Ctrl + Right Alt`.